# xml javascript get attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, attributes

I am trying to code a simple weather app.

I am having trouble targeting the attribute, there are several nodes that are named the same, but differentiated by the attribute.

```
displayWET(0);

function displayWET(i) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp, i);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?   lat=33.749&lon=-84.388&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data");

var summary;
var wetSummary;
s = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weather"[1]);


for (var i=0;i<s.length;i++)
     {
        wetSummary=s[i].getElementsByTagName("weather-conditions");
        summary =  wetSummary.item(i).getAttributeNode("weather-summary");

     }



document.getElementById("showWet").innerHTML =

 "<h2 class='title'>ATLANTA</h2>" + "<h2 class='number'>" +
x[1].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
+ "&deg; F</h2><br/>" +
"H: " +
x[0].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
+ "&deg; F / L: " +
x[0].getElementsByTagName("value")[7].childNodes[0].nodeValue
+ "&deg; F<br/><img src='" +
x[1].getElementsByTagName("icon-link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
+ "'/><br/>" + "<br/><strong>Today:</strong> " +
x[0].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
+ "<br/>" +  summary 

;

}
```

The var summary is returning undefined. Here is the link to my xml.

http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.7712&lon=-84.3764&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `"weather"[1]` evaluates to `"e"`.  You may want `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weather");`, since you're about to loop through each `<weather>` tag.

Comment: i made that edit and now it returns null.

Comment: the data i want is in the second instance of "weather" so that is why i added the [1], is there a better way to target the second instance of weather?

Comment: rather than running a for loop through the whole document, i just targeted the data element directly,     s = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weather-conditions")[13].getAttribute("weather-summary");                                                                              but thank you for taking the time to answer! it helped me rethink the whole logic.

Comment: FYI for anyone else: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weather")[1];` get's the second instance of the `<weather>` tag.